# Navigating to parent's screen from a nested navigator in react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm having trouble navigating back to my homepage from a nested navigator.

My files are structured like this :

```
const ParentNav = StackNavigator(
    /* Route configs */
    {
        Login: {
            screen: Login
        },
        Signup: {
            screen: Signup
        },
        Authenticated: {
            screen: MainNav
        }
    },

    /* Navigator configs */
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        headerMode : 'none'
    }
);

export default () => <ParentNav/>;
```

Login's componentWillMount() :

```
ls.save('login-key', this.props.navigation.state.key)
```

And then...

```
const MainNav = TabNavigator(
    // Route configs
    {
        "My App": {
            screen: AppNavigator
        },
        "Action": {
            screen: ActionNavigator
        },
        "Settings": {
            screen: Settings
        },
    },

    // Navigator configs
    {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom'
    }
);

export default () => <MainNav />;
```

My Settings page has a "Logout" button, and I can't figure out how to send the user back to the ParentNav's Login screen from there.

Settings :

```
componentWillMount() {
    ls.get('login-key')
    .then(key => {
        console.log('Setting backAction with key ', key)
        backAction = NavigationActions.back({
            key: key
        });
    })
}

_handleLogout = () => {
    auth.logout()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Dispatch');
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(backAction);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first screen in the stack navigator is the login page, you can just dispatch a [`back` action](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Back) with the key of the first screen (you'll need to save it somewhere).

If it isn't, you can dispatch a [`reset` action](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#reset) with the login page set to be the only screen in the stack.

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login'})
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I'm new with this; How do you set the key? Or at least, get the key that was attributed by default, if any?

Comment: Take a look at `navigator.state`. It should have the key for each screen in the stack.

Comment: So, on my Login page, I stored the key in the local storage. 

I define the reset action in Settings' componentWillMount() and call this.props.navigation.dispatch in the Logout button handle... 

Did I do something wrong? It stays on the same page. :/

Comment: Add the new code to the question, it's hard to know what's going on without it.

Comment: My bad! Just added it. :)

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1481), the key needs to be of the screen you go back *from*, not to. So, if the stack is `login -> authenticated`, you'll need to provide the `authenticated` key. I think going with reset is easier.